# Discord bot failing to call username of person who calls it

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot say a simple message whenever someone tells it 'hello'. Currently, the code of the command itself looks like this:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const greeter = "default";
const greetOptions = [
    `Hello, ${greeter}. It's very nice to hear from you today.`
]
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('hello')
        .setDescription('say hi to Hal!'),
    execute(message, args) {
        let greeter = message.user.username;
        msg.channel.send(greetOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * greetOptions.length)]);
    },
};
```

The code I am using to manage when commands are typed looks as follows:

```
let prefix = "hal, ";
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
    const command = args.toLowerCase();
    console.log(`${message.author.tag} called ${command}`);

    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try {
        client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.channel.send({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});
```

When I run it, it throws the error, "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to mention a user you can do `${message.author}`. But if you want to say for ex. `Hello, Brandon` then you need to do `${message.author.username}`. The message `${message.author.tag}` does not always function and also I recommend you `const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author` or just `const user = message.author` for short so then you can do `${user.username}`. Maybe this might fix the bot failing to respond otherwise if it doesn't tell me.
Fix the first code and change `msg.channel.send` to `message.channel.send`.

Comment: I tried this fix - I have to make that statement with the 'let' command inside my execute as the message is not valid outside the execute segment. However, doing this throws a different error - "msg is not defined".

Comment: bruh change msg to message or do const msg = message;

Comment: when your sending it on the first code

Comment: Thanks, @Brandon Torreglosa. Somehow I didn't notice that instance amidst all the other ones.

Comment: no problem mate see you and whenever you need me again just ping.